# Hacer consulta para obtener valoración media en MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, tablas, sql

Necesitaría hacer un INNER JOIN de 3 tablas para obtener unos datos. La cuestión es que necesito que los valores de una columna tengan redondeo y sea un promedio. No obstante, los valores se repiten y no encuentro una solución salvo la de hacer una 4º tabla...

Las tablas son las siguientes:

La tabla "user".

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nick` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `town` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
 UNIQUE KEY `nick` (`nick`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

La tabla "book".

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
 `id_book` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `author` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `bookTitle` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `genre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `numberPages` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_book`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Y la tabla "rating".

```
CREATE TABLE `rating` (
 `id_rating` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `valoration` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_rating`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `rating_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

En resumen, quiero hacer un INNER JOIN de esas tres tablas, y añadir la información de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT user_id, ROUND(AVG(valoration)) AS averageValoration FROM `rating` GROUP BY user_id
```

De tal manera que salgan los libros y en la columna de "valoration" la valoración media de los USUARIOS (id_user), aunque ésta se repitan, puesto que quiero hacer un buscador avanzado donde salgan los libros, los usuarios que tienen esos libros y las valoraciones de esos usuarios en cada uno de los libros.

Espero haberme explicado bien. Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Es posible que te falte agregar DISTINCT aquellos valores que quieras discriminar, esos que se repite

Comment: Con esto lo que ocurre es que sale solo una línea :/ Gracias por responder!

Comment: @Jotaerre, por favor, modifica la pregunta incluyendo datos de muestra y qué resultado esperas a partir de esos mismos datos. No termino de entender ni la estructura de tu base de datos, ni lo que necesitas exactamente. Con el ejemplo se verá mucho más claro y podremos ayudarte. Gracias